# Home made apple cider vinegar

Tags: vinegar

I have several jars of apple cider vinegar fermenting for 3-4 months now. Stored away in a cool dark place. I just pulled them out. One gallon jar had a rip in the paper lid at the rubber band. Fruit flies got in the jar and drowned. At least 30. Should I throw the whole thing out?  What a waste.

Comment: Will it just be you eating vinegar steeped with dead insects, or do you intend to serve it to other people? Do you plan to tell them about the insects, or keep it a secret?